# insert a data into a specific locations in dataframe with dataframe.loc in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cell

I tried insert a data into a specific locations in dataframe with two options.
Option 1 uses fixed colum label and variable index label and
Option 2 uses fixed index label and variable colum label and
then Option 1 has no error but Option 2 has warning
`` PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()` ``

Option 1 : no warning

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()

for col in range(200):
    df.loc[str(col),'A']=str(col)
```

Option 2 : **warning**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
for col in range(200):
    df1.loc['A',str(col)]=str(col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is really not designed to add/insert data repeatedly in a loop. This creates many expensive intermediates.

Rather loop with a low level object (list/dictionary) and construct the DataFrame **once** in the end.

First code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {str(i):i for i in range(200)}})
```

Second code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': {str(i):i for i in range(200)}}, orient='index')
```